# PhoneGap disable caching

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, caching

I've made a html file where I'm using JavaScript to view a list of table from a textfile. The issue here is that *every time I enter the page in PhoneGap on my tablet, it shows me the old content*. When trying it on my computer, I have to type `Ctrl + F5` to get the latest content.

How can I make my html page update the content in PhoneGap?

I found some meta tags for disabling the cache, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the following plugin :

https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-cache

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady);
function onDeviceReady()
{
    var success = function(status) {
        alert('Message: ' + status);
    }

    var error = function(status) {
        alert('Error: ' + status);
    }

    window.cache.clear( success, error );
}
```

This will clear the cache of your application everytime you launch it.

You can comment alerts in the callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Should I use this in the index.html page (the first loaded page) or inside the file where I want to clear the content from the table?

Comment: I think it doesn't really matter but I'll use it in the first loaded page. If you have already an onDeviceReady function add the code of my answer in it

Comment: Alright, don't have the code now, but will try it out tomorrow and accept this solution if it works. Thanks.

Comment: It worked perfectly, inserted it into the index file.