# Phonegap Developer storing files in development on cache

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, caching

I'm developing a Phonegap application using Phonegap Developer for Android. And I have a big problem: after I change some file, like `index.html`, or `some.js`, `some.css`, `some.png`... it doesn't works on app. Basically the application reload and I get same old file.

I tried use four fingers to reload, and three fingers to back to application home, and connect again. I tried inspect via desktop and force `location.reload(true)`. Nothing. The unique solution is force close Phonegap Developer and open it again.

Even if I put something like `some.js?$timestamp`, it doesn't works, because `index.html` is cached too. I guess that this cache is cleaned time in time, but I don't know how much. And some changes I need test imediatly.

Answer (score 1):

don't know if this is the same issue I had two days ago, but the simptoms are like you described. I finally solved it upgrading phonegap. Maybe it's not the best solution, but it worked for me.

```
$ sudo npm update -g phonegap
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check a similar answer here : [PhoneGap disable caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358408/phonegap-disable-caching/30358611?noredirect=1#comment48830843_30358611)

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady);
function onDeviceReady()
{
var success = function(status) {
    alert('Message: ' + status);
}

var error = function(status) {
    alert('Error: ' + status);
}

window.cache.clear( success, error );
}
```

Comment: My problem is that this solution depends of a plugin. Is possible install plugins on [*Phonegap Developer*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.phonegap.app)?

Comment: I'm not using Phonegap Developer. However as everything depends on plugins when you develop a cordova project, I doubt that you can't add a plugin