# Cordova: How to clear cache of mobile on app logout?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Hi i have developed one mobile application in codova with ionic framework. I have build the app and started testing on android mobile. On logout click i have added this code behind:

```
        window.localStorage.clear();
```

But on mobile testing time when i logged out & tried login again. It showed me the same data after login twice, one below the another. How to stop coming that one?

My controller code:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("userid", UserId);
window.localStorage.setItem("username", Email);
window.localStorage.setItem("name", Username);
window.localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
```

My logout code:

```
$scope.clearStorage = function() {
console.log('logging out');
window.localStorage.clear();
$state.go('intro');
}
```

i am accessing data as:

```
var queryString = base_url + "get/requestChartData.php";
var data = $.param({userid:window.localStorage.userid, token:token, chart: chartType});

$http.post(queryString, data).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
```

Comment: how you access to your data & set your data ? show your controller

Comment: ok wait i am updating the question

Comment: cann you add after you clear your localStorage.clear() a log : console.log("User id shall be empty",window.localStorage.userid) ?

Comment: i got what i need is but don't know is it the best practice or not. I have to clear all the arrays data that i have defined in the main controller. But that means whatever array or variables i have taken i should clear the one by one. Is there any other way so that i will clear all the data using that just once? localStorage doesnt make any problem after clear it is getting clear i checked in browser too...

Comment: Well if you need to clear cache , there is a plugin for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358408/phonegap-disable-caching/30358611#30358611

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in your logout function

$timeout(function(){

```
  $ionicHistory.clearCache();
```

}, 500);

$state.go('intro');